# Run gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabi

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I download and install `gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabi`

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

When I tried to run `gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabi` I got command not found

How can i run it now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the executable path is not added to your PATH variable. Also using a package manager to download the cross-compiler toolchain is not a good idea.

Get the zipped binary(the one you need depends on the architecture of the CPU and the ARM version) from [here](https://www.linaro.org/downloads/), unzip it using  `tar -xf filename.tar.xz`

After extraction, you can find the compiler binaries in the bin folder of the extracted files, you can use them from the same folder(./binaryname) or add them to your path. You also have to set some environment variables depending on the program you are compiling

The gcc compiler for compiling to native(arm) target code is the binary named "arm-eabi-gcc".

Alternatively you can also use clang.